# Mongo replication servers on different versions

Tags: mongodb, x86, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

I want to move a `mongodb` cluster between data-centers, and i decide to build a server to the new data-center and join it on the existing cluster, in order to pull all data to the new data-center.

Afterwards i am planning to make it primary and add more nodes to new DC. until now i have tried only clusters with the same version. My question is, on the old DC i have `mongodb 2.0 32-bit` , on new DC i will install 2.4 64-bit, is there any known issue on replication between different `mongodb` versions?

Comment: I made it on test environment without any issue, i will go to live and update the thread.